# Display text w/ brushed values in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have some svg circles along a single axis and d3.brushX activated. [In this small Observable example,](https://observablehq.com/@daranzolin/percentage-comparison-concept) I want displayText to respond to the brush, displaying the number of circles selected by the brush.

The values currently respond to the brush, but it just writes the text on top of the existing value. How do I clear it every time the brush moves?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the text a class, select all DOM elements of the class and remove them right before you append the text within your brushed function.

```
      svg.selectAll(".label").remove()
      svg.append("text")
        .attr("class","label")
        .attr("x", width/2)
        .attr("y", 50)
        .text(displayText)
```

OR create the text element outside your brushed function

```
       svg.append("text")
        .attr("class","label")
        .attr("x", width/2)
        .attr("y", 50)
```

...then, just change the text within the brushed function

```
     svg.select(".label").text(displayText)
```

The second approach is probably better...